# How to remove the background behind the lines

Tags: python, seaborn

I created a line plot using seaborn. Now, I want to remove the background behind the line plot to make it transparent. How can I archive this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documentation of [**`seaborn.lineplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), you can set `ci` to `None`.

> ***ci : int or “sd” or None***
> Size of the confidence interval to draw when
> aggregating with an estimator. “sd” means to draw the standard
> deviation of the data. Setting to None will skip bootstrapping.

```
sns.lineplot(..., ci=None)
```